# Entity Framework Core Seeding 3 related entities

Tags: entity-framework, seeding

I have 3 entities that are related (Account Groups to Account Categories to Accounts).  I am trying to seed the database.  The code below works for seeding Account Group and Account Category but I am unsure how to seed the next level which is account.

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXinE.png)

```
    var Revenue = new AccountGroup()
            {
                AccountGroupName = "Revenue",
                AccountCategories = new List<AccountCategory>()
                {
                    new AccountCategory { AccountCategoryName = "Base Business Build" },
                    new AccountCategory { AccountCategoryName = "Contract" },
                    new AccountCategory { AccountCategoryName = "Other" }
                }
            };

            _context.AccountGroups.Add(Revenue);

            _context.AccountCategories.AddRange(Revenue.AccountCategories);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Examples of accounts in the Base Business Build Category would be:
   Project work,
   Vertical Sales.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the relation ?  One `AccountGroup` to Many `AccountCategory`, and then, One `AccountCategory` to Many `Account` ?

Comment: Yes, so basically, you just repeat what you did and change `AccountGroup` for `Revenue.AccountCategory` and change `AccountCategory` for `AccountCategory.Account`... I mean... it's the same relation type

Comment: And also you need a `foreach( ChildType  item IN ParentType.Children){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like :

```
foreach(AccountCategories singleCategories  in Revenue.AccountCategories)
{
    _context.Account.AddRange(singleCategories.Acount)
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.